# lapply doesn't pass dataframe column element-wise to custom function

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply

I know that there are similar questions, but I am just not able to understand why this isn't working. I've seen many examples and maybe some interaction is just not clear to me, or maybe I'm just influenced by the ease I had in doing this with python (which is not good unfortunately for statistical models). This function should work like pandas's "apply" in my mind.

I have a simple dataframe and I'm interested in mapping the values of one of my columns. This is my code:

```
# Define encoding function
encode_state <- function(x){
    print(length(x))
    res <- 0
    if ((x == 'I') || (x == 'R')){
        res <- 0
    } else if (x == 'V'){
        res <- 1
    } else if (x == 'S'){
        res <- 2
    }
    return(res)
}

# Apply the function
mydata['state'] <- lapply(mydata['state'], "encode_state")
```

It gives me the error/warning: `argument '%s' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`

So I checked the length of the element passed to my function by lapply, and it just seems that the whole column is passed, instead of the function being applied to each element of my column. By documentation (and again examples) it just seems to me that the function should be applied element-wise, so any suggestions?

Comment: Update: It seems to work if I use "mapvalues". Still it doesn't explain me why the operation is not element-wise (and how could I do that?)
`mydata['state'] <- lapply(mydata['state'], function(x) mapvalues(x, c("I", "R", "V", "S"), c(0, 0, 1, 2)))`

Comment: `mydata[['state']]` is the vector. `mydata['state']` is a dataframe with one column.

Comment: You are using `lapply` with `"encode_state"` which is just a character string, not a function name. Remove the quotes and retry.

Answer (score 0):

Because mydata['state'] is a dataframe and not a vector

```
length(mydate['state'])
class(mydata['state'])
```

mydata[,'state'] would be a vector and will work element wise

```
length(mydate[,'state'])    
class(mydate[,'state'])
```

Comment: I see the selection doesn't really work as I thought, thanks and sorry for the silly question. Still I saw many examples doing the same thing I did and that was confusing!